# Count how many field of an array are full

Tags: c, arrays

Hey guys i'm want to use a structure in C and see witch of  the array are empty and count how many arrays are full

Structre

```
    typedef struct
{
    char nome[30];
    int num_juiz;
} juiz;

typedef struct
{
    char nome[30];
    int num_atleta;
} atleta;
```

Function

```
void inserir_pontuacao(nota inserir[],juiz juiz[], atleta atleta[])
{
    int njuiz=1;
    int natleta=1;
    int i=1;
    while (i<=100)
    {
        if(strcmp(juiz[i].num_juiz, NULL))
        {
            njuiz++;
        }
        if(strcmp(atleta[i].num_atleta, NULL))
        {
            natleta++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",njuiz);
    printf("%d\n",natleta);
}
```

Can you help me
Thanks

Comment: `strcmp(ANY, NULL)` is wrong.

Comment: Your array indexing should go from 0..99 not 1..100 (assuming 100 elements)

Comment: And how can i do what i want?

Comment: Teacher say whe ahve to do this

Comment: Why can't you add one more field in the struct say `isUsed` and set that to 1 when you have something written to your char array and set it to 0 when it is NULL

Comment: @Gopi  I Dont see how it should help.
Its better to understand what he wants to do. You dont really need a flag here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

João Reis,

You're using strcmp function to compare an integer element.
The correct comparison may be:

```
if ( juiz[i].num_juiz > 0 )
  njuiz++;
```

Maybe, if you want to use strcmp, you should change your data type to char *, like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char nome[30];
    char num_juiz[8];
} juiz;
```

[Edit] In addition, you should look to your set up function, to be sure your data is beeing correctly added to struct. For example:

```
for ( i = 0; i < MAX_JUIZES; i++ ) 
  juiz[i].num_juiz = 20
```

[Edit2] Make sure, your function params are correctly declared outside. Remember its an array of structures. Similar to a Linked List.